# Best Way to Report Calibration

Tags: boosting, calibration

I'm wondering what is the most accepted way to report metrics for model calibration. I have seen R2, slope and the brier score being used.

In addition, are there any packages in Python that can be used to create a calibration curve with a 95% confidence interval/error bars. I am using an XGBClassifier.

Thanks!